# how to login as email/phone number

Tags: login, magento-1.9.1.1, mobile-login

[image][image]

> Now i am login with email id only. But i would like to login with mobile number also. So, how to login with mobile number in magento-1.9.1.1? I have tried "Netgo_UserandMobile" Extension from magento connect manager, But it is not working.Any solution for this one.

Comment: Any error in that extension

Comment: no error ,but it not be working.

Comment: This extension is available in Magento 1 
https://magecomp.com/magento-mobile-login.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is extension available at magento commerce follow below link and you find extension https://github.com/diglin/Diglin_Username
2. Install the extension into your admin panel.
3. Logout once and login again
4. Goto system-->configuration-->login with mobile number-->enable-->yes-->save configuration
5. Register new account and login with mobile number.

Comment: I installed this one.But didn't work.

Comment: actuaay,i added extension "customer mobile login".It will not be effect on the page.

Comment: yes enable in admin pannel.